# Sometimes getting 503 when trying to POST comments

Tags: bug, comments

Very rarely, and seemingly randomly, I'm getting a 503 (Backend read error) when trying to POST to `/posts/123456/comments`. I encounter it when hitting the "submit" button on the comment form on a post.

When I try to post it again immediately, it works fine.

Comment: Could it be that while you writing comment your session ends and then  post do not pass authorization ?

Comment: @DaniilT. That would trigger a 4xx error, not 503.

Comment: @Gothdo is this happening in debug mode or in production ?

Comment: @DaniilT. I thought of that, but then, you'd get a 4xx error, like Gothdo says. Additionally, it wouldn't work 1 second later when I hit submit again, if my session is invalid.